# If statements with names and an input

Tags: python, if-statement, input

this is python 3
I just did this program with numbers but I can't make it work with names.
This is how I wrote it

```
x=input("write a actor from a famous movie:")
if (x==Matt Damon):
    print ("Jason Bourne")
else:    
    print ("type another actor")
```

As I understand it's the `==` section that's wrong but I don't know why. My other thought is to write something like :
`MattDamon=Jason Bourne` etc.

But that doesn't work either, I feel like I'm missing something minor to pull it off.

I would be very pleased if someone could help med, thnx!!

Comment: `if x == "Matt Damon"` ? Quote the string literal

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should have posted the error message and traceback (cf [mcve]) - not that important in this specific case (the issue is obvious) but most of the time those are required informations - "doesn't work" is a totally useless description of a problem ;-)

Comment: thank you very much for your time and answer

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes for name in the `if` condition -(`x=="Matt Damon"`)

```
x=input("write a actor from a famous movie:")
if (x=="Matt Damon"):
    print ("Jason Bourne")
else:    
    print ("type another actor")
```

Comment: please take care of proper code formatting in your answers (fixed).

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'm new to this website so i take all feedback and try to improve. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

> I feel like I'm missing something minor

It's actually far from "minor" - not in the "how to make it work", but in that it shows you don't get the basic syntax rules, which you should learn first and foremost (we've all been thru this, and it's indeed not that obvious when it's your very first experience with a programming language).

Here:

```
if (x==Matt Damon):
```

[According to Python's syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html), `Matt` and `Damon` are [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) (variables or function names), not strings, which raises a `SyntaxError` since juxtaposing two identifiers that way makes no sense and so is invalid syntax indeed.

If you tried with one single term instead, ie:

```
if (x==Matt):
```

then the syntax would be valid, and Python would try to compare variable `x` with a variable named `Matt`. The result could be either a `NameError` if you didn't previously defined a variable named `Matt`, or, if you defined it, whatever the test would yield depending on how `Matt` it was defined.

[As documented](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings), if you want a litteral string, you have to use quotes around the string, ie:

```
if (x=="Matt Damon"):
```

I strongly suggest you do [the full official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), and then browse the doc for more details. This usually works better (and is faster) than trying things at random and posting here in despair ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your time and thoughts on my problem, i will do so :D